# In Java, how can I create a class property that selects from different enums?

Tags: java, enums

EDIT2: More explanation.

The concept is for sentences to be constructed from "phrases," which are just strings, and "attributes," which can only be specific words.

Example: "The" *system* "will" *action*.

*system* and *action* (attributes) can only be certain words, so I wanted them to be enums. But I also thought that in general they're accomplishing the same thing, so I thought I'd make a class called Attribute that's either a System or Action.

========================================

EDIT: Posting my real code instead of explaining a simple example...

The key part is the unwritten constructor at the end. I'm hoping to be able to create an attribute of either system or action type.

```
public class Attribute {
    // Subsystem Enum
    public enum subsystem {
        PROCESSOR ("Processor"), 
        MONITOR ("Monitor"), 
        MOUSE ("Mouse"), 
        KEYBOARD ("Keyboard");

        private String value;

        private subsystem(String value){
            this.value = value;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return value;
        }
    }

    // Action Enum
    public enum action {
        EXECUTE ("Execute"), 
        DISPLAY ("Display"), 
        CLICK ("Click"), 
        ACCEPT ("Accept");

        private String value;

        private action (String value){
            this.value = value;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return value;
        }
    }   

    // Constructor methods
    public Attribute() {}
    // TODO: Constructor that creates an Attribute of type System or Action

}
```

I've searched all over for this, but can't find an example. I have a Java class property that needs to take values from one of several enums.

As an example, a store might sell Fruits, Vegetables, or Meat.

The Fruit enum might takes values: APPLES, ORANGES.

The Vegetable enum might take values: PEAS, CARROTS.

The Meat enum might take values: BEEF, CHICKEN.

I want the Store class to contain a property of type Fruit, Vegetable, or Meat, so that I can set the requisite values.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Most of us prefer to help those who show just a little evidence of effort. We're volunteers and can be funny that way.

Comment: Although Store can have an overridden method that might work, but the OP needs to show us something.

Comment: @Andreas: also enums can share a single interface...

Comment: OP, Action and Subsystem contain orthogonal information, and so surely you wouldn't want a single field to hold information for one or the other. You'd create two fields, one for each type of enum.

Comment: The tenor of this question suggests an individual locked into a specific approach. Perhaps explaining what really needs to be accomplished would be better. Seems a bit like [the XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @KevinO: you're right. After looking at his edits, he looks to be possibly confusing data with code, and that enum might be the wrong way to approach this. Much more flexible approaches are available, some that would allow allow flexible additions and removals of subjects and predicates, including by text file or xml or database.

Comment: Close vote removed, down-vote changed to an up-vote due to improvements to the question. Thank you Ted for the efforts.

Comment: Thanks, Mr. Hovercraft. Lesson Learned: Post code rather than a toy example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your requirement is not really clear, but it sounds like you might be looking for a [generic class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html):

```
class Attribute<T extends Enum<T>> {
    final T value;

    Attribute(T value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

Now you can create `Attribute`s with specific enum types:

```
Attribute<Subsystem> a1 = new Attribute<>(Subsystem.PROCESSOR);
Attribute<Action> a2 = new Attribute<>(Action.EXECUTE);
```

---

After your edits, I'm thinking you might want `Attribute` as a common interface for your enums:

```
public interface Attribute {
    String getName();
}

public enum Subsystem implements Attribute {
    PROCESSOR ("Processor"), 
    MONITOR ("Monitor"), 
    MOUSE ("Mouse"), 
    KEYBOARD ("Keyboard");

    private final String value;

    private Subsystem(String value){
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return value;
    }
}

public enum Action implements Attribute {
    EXECUTE ("Execute"), 
    DISPLAY ("Display"), 
    CLICK ("Click"), 
    ACCEPT ("Accept");

    private final String value;

    private Action(String value){
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

Now you can do this:

```
Attribute a1 = Subsystem.PROCESSOR;
Attribute a2 = Action.EXECUTE;
```

Comment: Thanks! I will see if the generic class works for me

Comment: @Ted, out of curiosity, which solution were you after?

Comment: I used the interface. It works nicely, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I am certain I will receive downvotes for this approach, and I will delete the answer after a couple of them. In no way am I advocating such an approach.

The basic approach can be achieved through using an interface.The specific methods of the interface need to be considered. I have provided only a single one for illustrative purposes.

**Edit:** removing the `<E>` from the interface. As properly noted in a comment, not really needed for this approach.

```
static interface Item
{
    public String name();
}

static enum Fruit implements Item { Apples, Oranges, Pears };
static enum Vegetable implements Item { Carrots, Peas, Potatoes };
static enum Meat implements Item{ Beef, Chicken };
static enum Seafood implements Item
{ Salmon, Trout, Halibut, Shrimp };


static class GeneralStore
{
    List<Item> items = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addItem(Item it)
    {
        items.add(it);
    }

    public List<Item> getItems()
    {
        return Collections.unmodifiableList(items);
    }
}


public static void main(String[] args)
{
    GeneralStore gs = new GeneralStore();

    Item itf = Fruit.Apples;
    gs.addItem(itf);

    Item itm = Meat.Beef;
    gs.addItem(itm);


    System.out.println(gs.getItems());

    for (Item it : gs.getItems()) {
        // call the method on the interface
        System.out.println(it.name());
    }
}
```

Sample Output:

> [Apples, Beef]
>   Apples
>   Beef

The original class may be deduced, but if there is sufficient commonality, the interface approach could work. It depends a lot on the use cases.

Constructive feedback to improve the answer welcomed.

Comment: thank you! I will definitely look at using an interface

Comment: Why add the generic `<E>`? It's not doing anything.

Comment: @Andreas, a fair question. I had a slightly different implementation in mind when I first started writing, but the interface without it works fine (as shmosel's answer also demonstrates). It may be dropped without affecting the functionality. I'll update the answer by removing them. Thank you for the feedback.